# NSXMLParser Error When Using with Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser to fetch some XML from a remote source. The downloadPeopleDirectory initiates the NSXMLParser as shown below:

```
 func downloadPeopleDirectory() {

        var xml = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://someurl/People.xml"))
        xml.delegate = self
        xml.parse()
    }
```

When I add the didEndElement implementation then it starts failing with "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error" at the xml.parse() line. The downloadPeopleDirectory is only invoked once in viewDidLoad of the UITableViewController class.

What am I doing wrong>

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your `didEndElement` function and step through the code to see where the problem is. Post your `didEndElement` function here for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks! didEndElement is an empty method with no implementation. As soon as I add the didEndElement method (empty with no implementation) I get the exception as explained in the question above.

Comment: How do you want to parse the XML document without implementing the methods `didStartElement`, `foundCharacters`  and `didEndElement`? Please check one of the tutorials available on how to use NSXMLParser. You need to implement the `NSXMLParserDelegate`protocol.

Comment: I have implemented didStartElement, foundCharacters but as soon as I add didEndElement it throws the exception.

Comment: Can you post more code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I'm developing an iOS app since several months so it made its way through all the beta versions of Xcode. The XMLParser part in that app has this signature:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
    ...
}
```

This works without errors.

When I remove the exclamation marks, the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`